# Load error is not captured by try catch block

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I have a code like:

```
try{
  ...
} catch(error){
  ...
};
```

In `try` block, there is a function call that makes a request to a server. When there is no resource on the server, an error is raised (as I can see in Google Chrome's developers tool):

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

and I am trying to catch it in the `catch` block, but the error is not captured.

Is it a feature of JavaScript that load error is not captured by `try` `catch` block?

Comment: How are you making the request? I'm new to Javascript myself, but errors like that usually aren't exceptions.

Comment: @Linuxios I don't know the exact command that makes a request. I make a call to a function in a library, which tries to load a certain file.

Comment: Can we see that code (the call to the library)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, when requesting information from a server (for instance, via ajax, by setting the `src` of an `img` element, etc.), you don't get an *exception*, but you do get an error event or callback, not least because the code doing the request finishes before the request does, so it's impossible to throw an exception at that point. Since you haven't shown how you're requesting the information, it's impossible to be more specific, but this is why you're not getting an exception.

For instance, with an ajax request, if there's an error you see the ajax request complete but with the `statusCode` of the `XMLHttpRequest` object being an error status code, rather than 200. E.g.:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        // The request is complete; did it work?
        if (xhr.statusCode >= 200 && xhr.statusCode < 300) {
            // Yes
        }
        else {
            // No, got a code outside the 2xx range
        }
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", "/your/url/here", true);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: I see. So a non-200 response is not an exception. It is misleading that Google Chrome developers tool displays that together with other exceptions.

Comment: @sawa: No, the web console shows a *lot* of things. Exceptions, request failures, warnings related to using deprecated APIs. There's no promise there that errors are exceptions.